# Can't remove non-empty folder when using nodejs ftp plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm trying to remove folder with its contents using rmdir method (from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) npm package) with recursive parameter that is set to true.

Documentation says:

> If recursive, this call will delete the contents of the directory if it is not empty.

But I'm getting an error:

```
throw new Error(err)
             ^
Error: Error: /path_on_ftp: Directory not empty
```

Anyone tried similar operation? Please help.

Comment: You don't have permissions on this directory or subdirectory.

Comment: But I'm logging as my primary account which can modify/delete files, e.g. using desktop ftp client - should this be a case then?

Comment: In most of the cases such error is raised on access rights problem.Try to delete those directories from your ftp admin panel or ftp client. Is it working?

Comment: yes, but once I create them again it raises same error (this script has to remove existing files and creating update version of them - but some of them should not exists anymore so I think it is better to just remove everything and re-upload)

Answer (score 0):

It is stated: `this call will delete the contents of the directory`. Not a directory itself.

Comment: but it raises the error I've mentioned above - so it calls `rmdir` on directory anyway? (so it's plugin development bug?)